# How to fix Timeout vs. Logger bug (where Logger blocks Timeout) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Ruby's Timeout::timeout system raises an exception, and so code that traps all exceptions (not just Errors) will break the mechanism.

Logger traps all exceptions that happen when writing messages and doesn't re-raise any, so a log-heavy program is likely to silently swallow the timeout Exception and keep going. I've filed a bug report.

I need a quick fix. My thought is to do this:

Pass my own Exception into Timeout::timeout (second parameter).

Copy the logger.rb file into my codebase, and use it instead of the language-provided logger.

Modify Logger to re-raise the timeout exception if it catches it.

Is there a better way?

Edit for clarity: I'm making calls to Logger inside of a Timeout::timeout block. For example, this code probably will not time out:

```
Timeout::timeout(1) {
  while true {
    @logger.debug("Hi world")
  }
}
```

Timeout works by raising an Exception. We all know that "rescue Exception" is bad. Well, Logger wraps its file writes in "rescue Exception" and doesn't re-raise. And so it traps the Timeout exception.

Comment: Can you give some more details about what you're trying to achieve? Why are you using `Timeout` inside of a `Logger` write?

Comment: I'm not. I'm using a Logger write inside of a Timeout.

Comment: Hmm. Why do you want to write to Logger inside of a Timeout?

Comment: By "inside a Timeout" I mean inside the code that will time out if it doesn't complete in time. I should be able to put large hunks of my codebase inside Timeout::timeout(n_secs) blocks and have it Just Work. My codebase does logger calls. Thus, logger calls happen inside a Timeout.